# SPAの"index.html"は一般に何と呼ばれていますか？

Tags: single-page-application

Single Page Applicationの呼び出し用のページとなるindex.html(若しくは別のファイル名)がありますが、このようなファイルは何と呼ばれていますか？

スタートスクリプト？ アプリケーションページ？

説明用の資料やミーティング時に漠然と「index.html」と呼んでしまっているので気になっています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

プログラムを実行するとき、プログラムの実行を始める場所を[**エントリーポイント**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9D%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)と呼びます。Web アプリケーションにおいては HTML 文書がエントリーポイントとなるため、質問文にあるような `index.html` はエントリーポイントと呼ぶことが出来ます。

その他のエントリーポイントとの混同が予想される場合には、「～のエントリーポイント」のように、助詞による限定を行えば少し分かりやすくなるかもしれません。ただし、「こう呼ばなければならない」という**決まりは特に無い**ため、具体的なファイル名 (`index.html` など) で呼ぶほうが、かえって分かりやすくなる場合もあると思います。